Why is my JavaScript is returning NaN when I run the code?
I started learning programming a little while ago, but I got stuck on the functions and intervals part.
What I wanted was a very simple system, to do multiplication, using HTML and JavaScript, passing the input numbers as parameters.
However, when I run the code, it returns NaN as the result.


let button = document.querySelector("#button");
let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);

function operacao(a, b) {
  let resp = a * b;
  return resp;
}

let resto = operacao(num1, num2)
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('resto').innerHTML = 'O resultado é: ' + resto
});
<label>
  Informe os numeros:  
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="num1">
  <p>x</p>
  <input type="number" id="num2">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<button id="button" onclick=(operacao)>Multiplicar</button>
<p id="resto"></p>




This question is similar to: Why is the value of my input always empty if I store it in a variable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Alternatively: Input.value returns NaN

You need to get the value of the inputs after clicking of the button. In your code the value of num1 & num2 will be undefined as
let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value); let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value); are executing before the button click and those inputs are initially empty


let button = document.querySelector("#button");;

function operacao(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b)
  let resp = a * b;
  return resp;
}


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value)
  let resto = operacao(num1, num2)
  document.getElementById('resto').innerHTML = 'O resultado é: ' + resto
});
<label>
  Informe os numeros:  
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="num1">
  <p>x</p>
  <input type="number" id="num2">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<button id="button" onclick=(operacao)>Multiplicar</button>
<p id="resto"></p>




Thank you very much bro, in this case it was a lack of attention or a lack of technical vision on my part.

You're reading the values from the inputs and performing a calculation on them immediately upon loading the page, before the user has had a chance to enter any values:
let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
//...
let resto = operacao(num1, num2)

Instead, read the values from the input and perform the calculation in the button click handler:


let button = document.querySelector("#button");

function operacao(a, b) {
  let resp = a * b;
  return resp;
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Calculate the result here...
  let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
  let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
  let resto = operacao(num1, num2);
  document.getElementById('resto').innerHTML = 'O resultado é: ' + resto
});
<label>
  Informe os numeros:  
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="num1">
  <p>x</p>
  <input type="number" id="num2">
</label>
<br>
<br>
<button id="button" onclick=(operacao)>Multiplicar</button>
<p id="resto"></p>




Thank you my friend, I am learning to have a better view of the code, thank you.
